# Flutter How can I make this animation "smoother"

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make this animation "smoother" (currently is restarts harshly on the 5 second refresh). I'd like for it to reverse maybe from the last angle?

I call this widget as this:

```
   SpinnerAnimation(body: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.earthAmericas, size: 33, color: Colors.white,),),
```

---

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SpinnerAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  late final Widget body;

  SpinnerAnimation({required this.body});

  @override
  _SpinnerAnimationState createState() =>
      _SpinnerAnimationState(body: this.body);
}

class _SpinnerAnimationState extends State<SpinnerAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final Widget body;

  _SpinnerAnimationState({required this.body});

  late AnimationController _controller;
  double change_rotation_speed = 1.2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat();

    //timer repeat every 5 seconds:
     Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => change_rotation_speed = randoDoubleGeneratorWithRange(1.2, 5) );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      child: body,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _controller.value * change_rotation_speed * math.pi,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
double randoDoubleGeneratorWithRange(double min, double max) {
 //return a random double value:
  var random = new Random();
  double result = min + random.nextDouble() * (max - min);
  //print(result);
  return result;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RotationTransition` and with `Animation`

```
.............
 late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> animationRotation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat(revere:true); // set true for reverse animation

    animationRotation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller);
  }
........

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      child: body,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return RotationTransition(
          turns: animationRotation,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
```

here demo link on Dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=e316af128311c0b42d7aef2fd9e037df

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Using this in combo with the timer + flip the reverse bool and it works! `  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => setState(() {
       widget.reverse = !widget.reverse;
     }) );`

Comment: you don't need `AnimatedBuilder` for that: `RotationTrsnsition` extends `AnimatedWidget` and rebuilds itself every time `turns` animation changes, so you can simply remove that `AnimatedBuilder`